# How can I add number of attempts to this java code

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Type password:\t");
        String command = reader.nextLine();
        if (command.equals("carrot")) {
            break;

        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong!");
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Right!");
    System.out.println("The secret is: jryy qbar!");
    reader.close();
}
```

I want to add up to 3 attempts here, i tried different combinations with for example "int n = 0; for (n>3; n++)" but it didn't really worked as expected

Comment: Try `for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++)`

Comment: See [The `for` Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials to learn how to use `for` correctly to create a loop.

Comment: As an alternative to a for loop initialize a variable e.g. `int attempts = 3;` decrement it in the loop and do `while( attempts > 0 ) { attempts--; ... }`. That way you can also tell the user how many attempts are left (`System.out.println("Wrong! Try again, you have " + attempts + " left.")`).

Comment: `int attemptsLeft = 3; for (; attemptsLeft > 0; attemptsLeft--)`

Answer (score 2):

You should add condition to your `while` clause.

```
import java.util.Scanner; public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 0;
    boolean isPasswordCorrect = false;
    while (i++ < 3) {
        System.out.print("Type password:\t");
        String command = reader.nextLine();
        if (command.equals("carrot"))  {
            isPasswordCorrect = true;
            break;
        } else{
            System.out.println("Wrong!");
        }
    }
    if(isPasswordCorrect) {
        System.out.println("Right!");
        System.out.println("The secret is: jryy qbar!");
    }
    reader.close();
    }
}
```

PROTIP: Scanner implements [AutoCloseable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), so you can use use the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) here:

```
try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  // your code using scanner
}
```

Comment: There's no bool datatype in java!

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int maxAttempts = 3;
    while (maxAttempts > 0) {
        System.out.print("Type password:\t");
        String command = reader.nextLine();
        if (command.equals("carrot"))  {
            System.out.println("Right!");
            break;
        } else{
            System.out.println("Wrong!");
            System.out.println("The secret is: jryy qbar!");
            maxAttempts--;
            if(maxAttempts == 0){
                System.out.println("You have reached the max number of attempts!");
            }
        }
    }
    reader.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.print("Type password:\t");
        String command = reader.nextLine();
        if (command.equals("carrot")) {
            System.out.println("Right!");
            System.out.println("The secret is: jryy qbar!");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong!");
        }

    }
    reader.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Type password:\t");
            String command = reader.nextLine();
            if (command.equals("carrot")) {
                System.out.println("Right!");
                System.out.println("The secret is: jryy qbar!");
                break;
            } else {
                i++;
                System.out.println("Wrong!");
                if (i == 3) {
                    System.out.println("Max attempts reached!! Exiting....");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        reader.close();
}
```

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt is there any issue with using System.exit ?? i have updated my answer to remove this but how does it matter?? it's just a main method?? can you enlighten me about what is wrong with my answer... cause i want to learn and improve my future answers

Comment: @Abishek `System.exit` is not for normal flow control. What if this function is used in a bigger program?